# Implementing TextWatcher for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, viewmodel, android-textwatcher

in my simple application i'm trying to implementing `TextWatcher` for some `EditText` that i have in layout,

i want to support getting default current edittext value which i set into that by code and support `afterTextChanged`, for implementing that i have this `EditText` into layout

[reference](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/two-way-data-binding-on-android-observing-your-view-with-xml/)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/instagram_page_name"
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textChangedListener="@{viewModel.usernameWatcher}"/>
```

`EditTextBindingAdapters` binding Adapter class:

```
public class EditTextBindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
    public static void bindTextWatcher(EditText editText, TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedWatcher(textWatcher);
    }
}
```

and my `ViewModel`:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private User user;
    private LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks;

    public LoginViewModel(LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks) {
        this.loginResultCallbacks = loginResultCallbacks;
        this.user = new User();
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM** 1:

on `EditTextBindingAdapters` class `addTextChangedWatcher` is uknown

**PROBLEM 2:**

how can i coding in `ViewModel` to use `EditTextBindingAdapters` class?

Comment: Use the function addChangedTextListener(textWatcher) instead of addTextChangedWatcher(textWatcher). You should'nt EditTextBindingAdapters in your ViewModel, the purpose of ViewModel is to retain your data and to allow you to access them from your view whenever you need it

Comment: @RobertLaFondue `EditTextBindingAdapters` is on another place as class, how can i use that into `ViewModel`?

Comment: You should use you ViewModel in the fragment/activity where you use your EditTextBindingAdapters, not the opposite